# BLAS library support for Apache Spark on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, docker, kubernetes, lapack

While BLAS/LAPACK libraries can cause immense speed-ups in local execution,
and even provide speed-up (to a lesser extent [due to various reasons](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21305)) for Apache Spark in cluster mode,
I was wondering whether the usage of BLAS libraries for Spark on top of a Kubernetes cluster does make sense at all.

One of the reasons is that, for BLAS to provide a significant speed boost, it has to be compiled against the specific local CPU, which might not be done quite so easily.

I am aware of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919866/docker-images-with-architecture-optimisation) that considers a more general inclusion of BLAS/LAPACK libraries in docker images. It would be interesting to hear whether someone already has experiences with this.
Since Kubernetes is also officially supported only since around March 2018, there seems to be little to no documentation on this out there, and popular docker images like alpine seem to have only little support for the necessary dependencies such as `glibc` etc.

To formulate a precise question: Does the usage of BLAS/LAPACK on Spark on Kubernetes even make sense? And what would be the smartest way to include this?

Comment: What does specific local CPU mean? Is it specific architecture like amd64? Specific vendor like Intel? Or specific processor model like Intel Xeon 8175?

Comment: Also what type of k8s deployment are you talking about? Is it deployment where you can manage hardware or cloud-based solution like GKE where you have API-access only?

Comment: I am talking about an unknown underlying architecture type on the Kubernetes cluster, which might change over the course of several deployments. The idea would be to ship it with multiple BLAS libraries and select the right one based on the target machine.I can see that the answer to this question might tend to "depends", but that still leaves the question as to how to load this, since the default alpine linux does not ship with a glibc, or rather with a sketchy workaround.

Comment: Well, often you can tell what will be processor type for a particular deployment. For example, if you run k8s on AWS m5 instances you will get Xeon 8175 cores for all your working nodes. Then you can run k8s job to build the image for this processor type and put it to the registry. After building an image run containers with it - they will match processor type and be optimized for it. As additional safeguard you can label the nodes and use nodeSelector to run and build images on the same type of nodes.